# Eclipse Hibernate Library downloads

Tags: eclipse, hibernate

Netbeans does comes with a set of library already to use, i havent found that feature on eclipse i manually have to downloads the library in order to have them and even have to configure on my enviroment??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, but it's no big deal.

Just download Hibernate itself and if you want to, [hibernate tools for eclipse](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/tools.html). I personally really like HQL editor from mentioned tools. Then use hibernate as simply, as adding it to your project's classpath.

Answer (score 1):

You can download Hibernate zip file from [www.hibernate.org](http://hibernate.org/orm/). In latest versions(Hibernate 4.3.7) jar files from only two folders need to be considered:

1. *lib/jpa*
2. *lib/required*

Make a new library in your project folder, and add jar file from the above folders.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea to simplify Library downloads is to use a build tool like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). It integrates well with Eclipse through the [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin. Maven downloads the libraries you need and m2eclipse makes them available to the Eclipse project.

Comment: yeah i've heard quite a bit about mave i haven't actuallly try it profesionaly, maybe you can suggest me a good starting point to use it with eclipse!! thanks!!